# The set where a sequence of measurable EXTENDED-REAL functions converge is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

**PROBLEM**

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence of **extended-real** functions on a measurable space $\{X,\Sigma\}$. Then:
> $$
> \{x \in X: f_n(x) \text{ converges}\} \in \Sigma
> $$
> where, by **convergence** I mean that the limit exists and is finite.

**ATTEMPT AT A SOLUTION**

*Proof*: The key strategy here consists of using the completeness of the $1$-dimensional Euclidean Space $\Bbb R$. However, there is the added problem that the members of the sequence may take infinite values. Nevertheless I claim that:
$$
\{x \in X: f_n(x) \text{ converges}\}
= \bigcap_{M \in \Bbb N_+} \bigcup_{N \in \Bbb N} \bigcap_{m,n \geq N} \{x \in X: |f_m(x)-f_n(x)| < 1/M\}
$$
where I write $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|$ only if it is well-defined (hence there is no indeterminate form). Now, let $A$ be the LHS and $B$ the RHS:

- $x \in A$

in this case $f_n(x)$ converges, therefore the sequence consists only of finite values for $n \geq N_{\infty}$ for some $N_{\infty} \in \Bbb N$; hence, if I fix $M \in \Bbb N_+$, then there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $N \geq N_{\infty}$ and $\forall m,n \geq N, |f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<1/M$; in conclusion $x \in B$.

- $x \in B$

if I fix $M=1$ then there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall m,n \geq N, |f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<1$ meaning that $\forall n \geq N$ the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n \geq N}$ must take only finite values and thus we can apply the aformentioned completeness to this tail of the sequence to show that it converges and $x \in A$.

It remains to show that $B \in \Sigma$. By $\sigma$-additivity it will be enough to show that $|f_m - f_n|^{-1}([-\infty, \alpha[) \in \Sigma$ for arbitrary $m,n \in \Bbb N$. First of all we need to notice that $f_m - f_n$ is defined only on
$$
E \equiv X / (f_m^{-1}(+\infty) \cap f_n^{-1}(+\infty)) \cup (f_m^{-1}(-\infty) \cap f_n^{-1}(-\infty))
$$
which is clearly measurable. Now, it can be shown that $f_m-f_n$ is measurable on the measure subspace $(E, \Sigma' \equiv \Sigma \cap \mathcal{P}E)$ so that $|f_m - f_n|$ is also measurable with respect to it. Therefore, since $\Sigma' \subseteq \Sigma$, $|f_m - f_n|^{-1}([-\infty, \alpha[) \in \Sigma$.

Is the proof correct?

---

Any answer or comment is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself more clearly.